What is the relation of parent env and the child env in MIT-Scheme?
When we call (environment-lookup system-global-environment name) where system-global-environment is the parent of top-level-environment, will it also look up in its child env?
From the doc, it seems that they are separate. If so, why we define parent env here?

The operations in this section reveal the frame-like structure of environments by permitting you to examine the bindings of a particular environment separately from those of its parent.

P.s. Is there some appropriate tag like env for this question in SO? (The recommendations like environment-variables are inappropriate here.)

The docs say that the name is found in the argument environment or ancestors.
So, no, child environments are not examined.


This follows the Principle of Least Surprise. When looking up a variable name you should not find stuff in local environments below your current scope (or context).
For example, if you have a global x and a function (or any lambda) with a local x, should anything other than the function’s code be able to find and use the local x (barring introspection capabilities)?
No, of course not. Look for a variable in the global context, you should only find global variables.
But if you look for a variable in a local context, should it not be found there, you should also look in it’s parent context, and keep looking until either the variable is found or we have run out of environments (the global environment being the last or topmost environment in the current scope).

You say "of course not", but that's a pretty modern perspective. It wasn't so long ago that dynamic variable scoping was a feature you could put in your language without people laughing at you. MIT Scheme is certainly old enough that it could behave differently, and you need to read the docs and/or ask questions like this to be sure.

Dynamic variable scoping will not enable you to access a variable that does not exist. A context belonging to an uninvoked function cannot ever make sense in any language with reentrancy.

Thanks for your explanation of why the design for "parent env and the child env" about inheritance is what it is. I am learning SICP and Software Design for Flexibility (SDF), so I don't have much programming background and don't know much about some jargons. For reference, "introspection" means https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20type%20introspection%20is,programming%20languages%20possess%20this%20capability. This is why we say "No, of course not." since dynamic variable scoping is implicitly banned.

"A context belonging to an uninvoked function cannot ever make sense in any language with reentrancy.": by reading "Similarly, code shared by two processors accessing shared data should be reentrant." in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing), func A may be interrupted by func B where both shares data C. Then "A context belonging to an uninvoked function" which will be run immediately may make sense. Maybe I misunderstood what you mean and what you want to say may be "an uninvoked function" until the program is finished.

RE: banning dynamic scoping • Eh, not really. There are two ways to look at scope: from the POV of how a program is structured (static or lexical scope), and from the POV of how a program executes (dynamic scope). Both are valid ways to look at things and neither impede introspection (or reflection). But from the POV of the language itself you must choose one as default. Tcl, for example, uses static scope (variable is local or global) by default, but you can switch to dynamic scoping (variable exists somewhere in the call stack) if you wish.

Reentrancy is just the ability of a function to continue to function properly (as if nothing interrupted it) if it is invoked multiple times. A local x may have multiple instantiations (once for each invocation of a function). My point was that should a language not provide that, then it would be feasible to have all variables exist for the lifetime of the program, and then you could inspect any variable at any time. This would be a fairly restrictive design, though, being unable to invoke a function in any recursive context.

Sorry if ambiguity. I didn't mean no "dynamic scope" implies no "introspection". I means the other direction: If "barring introspection capabilities", then as wikipedia says we can't "examine the type or properties of an object at runtime". Then this means we can't know "how a program executes", so no "dynamic scope". Is it that case?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
